# Why "down a" instead of "down from"?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

In Schindler's List (1993), a woman says a story:

> The trains arrived and the people were driven out with clubs. They
> were lined up in front of two big warehouses. One was marked "Cloak
> Room," and the other "Valuables." And there they were made to undress.
> A Jewish boy handed them pieces of string to tie their shoes together.
> They shaved their hair. They told them it was needed to make something
> special for U-boat crews. And then they were herded **down a** big
> corridor to bunkers with Stars of David on the doors and signs that
> said "Bath and  Inhalation Room."

Why "down a" instead of "down from"?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because it doesn't mean *down from*.

As well as its use as an adverb, *down* can also be a preposition. From dictionary.com:

> 20. in a descending or more remote direction or place on,
>     over, or along: They ran off down the street.

The meaning here is "along" - not necessarily in a downward direction.